# Coffeescript's Q.defer() then's call back

Tags: coffeescript, promise, q, deferred

I've seen

```
defereed.then (arg) =>
    function body
```

And

```
deferred.then ( 
    (arg) =>
        function  body
)
```

Can someone explain the difference?

This is from  https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug/blob/master/lib/engines/dbgp/dbgp-instance.coffee

Comment: If you refer to [this](https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug/blob/master/lib/engines/dbgp/dbgp-instance.coffee#L229-L247), that's just weird indentation.

Comment: The former form is dominant at the top half of that  file. The latter starts showing in the other half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Parenthesis are optional in [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#language):

> You don't need to use parentheses to invoke a function if you're passing arguments. The implicit call wraps forward to the end of the line or block expression.
>
> ```
> console.log sys.inspect object → console.log(sys.inspect(object));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make any difference. This is demonstrated by the code below.

```
doubleValue = (value) ->
  deferred = q.defer()
  deferred.resolve value * 2
  deferred.promise

doubleValue(3).then (result) =>
  console.log  result

doubleValue(4).then ((result) =>
  console.log  result
)
```